# Insert link to attached document in Outlook 365

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

I have a macro that had been working until I updated to Office 365.

I could attach a file or files and create a link in the body so that when the user clicks the link, it opens the attachment. This is very helpful if you have more than one attachment and need to write your email and keep the user in context of what you need to open. Instead of having to write the name of the attachment you can simply add a link (e.g. [ LINK ]) as a shortcut.

*This was working in 2013:*

```
Set MyAttachment= item.Attachments.item(i) 

MyAttachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", CStr(AttachRef)
```

Where AttachRef is the name of the attachment (string).

I then write the link in the email body with the address:

```
"cid:" & CStr(AttachRef)
```

And a description (string) the can be seen simply as:

```
[LINK]
```

Using:

```
Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor wdDoc.Hyperlinks.Add Selection.Range, Address:=iAddress, TextToDisplay:=iTextToDisplay
```

When you try to open the link, MS Office does not recognize the file and I get:

> "Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern. This location may be unsafe. cid:NAME"

Comment: and `Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor`

Comment: When you try to open the link, MS Office does not recognize the file and a message "Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern. This location may be unsafe. cid:NAME"

Comment: Have you test it on another PC?

Comment: No I haven't. But what is different in this same PC is the fact that, I know have 365 and had 2013 before. And it was ok before.

Comment: This piece of code worked fine also:
 `Private Sub attachementTool()
Dim msg, 
Dim attach
Set msg = Application.CreateItem(0)
msg.To = "me@gmail.com"
msg.Subject = "test link"
msg.HTMLBody = "<html><body>click <a href=""cid:attachCid1"">here</a> to open attachment <br />" & _
                "click <a href=""cid:attachCid2"">here</a> to open attachment</body></html>"
Set attach = msg.Attachments.Add("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\attach1.pdf")
attach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "attachCid1"
msg.Save
msg.Send
End Sub`

Comment: Is anyone out there able to help me?